# Multiple values in single column as an indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, indexed-view

I have such problem. My data is like:

Numers(Id)
Letters(Id, NumberId)

If I do Join query, I get output like that:

```
SELECT N.Id, L.Id
FROM Numbers N
JOIN Letters L ON N.Id = L.NumberId
```

And the output is

```
1 | a
1 | b
2 | a
2 | b
2 | c
```

But I would like to have all letters in one column, such as

```
SELECT N.Id, Letters.Value
FROM Numbers N
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
             (SELECT ',' + L.Id
              FROM Letters L
              WHERE L.NumberId = N.Id
              FOR XML PATH(''))) AS Letters(Value)
```

And the desired result is

```
1 | ,a,b
2 | ,a,b,c
```

Is there any way to make the second output to be a result of an Indexed-View?
I have tried with CROSS APPLY and subqueries, GROUP BY and DISTINCT. Maybe I could split this query into simpler queries? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, although it might be possible using `string_agg()` in later versions.

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't think so, there is nothing about Indexed View in the topic you have sent